# I need a help to change checkbox state when I change sheet with each different state in EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, ribbon

I am developing some VBA macro that has Ribbon checkbox.
How can I change a checkbox state when I change sheet with each different state in EXCEL VBA. 
I use a callback function "Workbook_sheetAcivate" at workbook module.
But I can't control checkbox state at this module.

Here is the checkbox code:

```
Sub checkBox1_getPressed(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
    rv = Cells(7, 13)
    MsgBox "체크박스1 , rv : " & rv 
    If rv = 1 Then 
        returnedVal = True
      Else
        returnedVal = False
    End If
   'oxIRibbonUI.Invalidate
End Sub
```

Comment: You'll have to be more specific and provide some code. What does the Ribbon checkbox do?

Comment: As @VBasic2008, mentioned.. your question or problem statement should be specific. Please provide the code you have used so far. Many times it gives the clue what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You cannot set the checkbox state directly. You need to invalidate the ribbon (or the individual checkbox control) when the value `rv` changes to force Excel to redraw the control when needed.